# How to pass array elements as separate method arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Scenario: A method takes arguments in this fashion

```
def my_method(model_name, id, attribute_1, attribute_2)
  # ...
end
```

All parameters are unknown, so I am fetching the model name from the object's class name, and the attributes I am fetching from that class returned as an array.

Problem: I have an array `["x", "y", "z"]`. I need to take the items from each array and pass them into the method parameters after the Model as illustrated above.

Is it even possible to "drop the brackets" from an array so to speak, but keep the items and their order in tact?

Comment: Without `*` you could just write `my_method(model_name, ary[0], ary[1], ary[2])`, not much of a problem here ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes, just use `*` before array:

```
my_method(model_name, *["x", "y", "z"])
```

it will result in:

```
my_method(model_name, "x", "y", "z")
```

`*` is a [splat operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion).

Comment: It is a very good way, I didn't know the splat operator before ;)

Comment: You saved me hours of frustration.

Comment: @Alex yeah, pretty handy. I use it all the time when I deal with CSVs and have variable number of columns per row

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is:

```
data = ["x", "y", "z"]
my_method(model_name, data[0], data[1], data[2])
```

The long way:

```
data = ["x", "y", "z"]
id_var = data[0]
attribute_1 = data[1]
attribute_2 = data[2]
my_method(model_name, id_var, attribute_1, attribute_2)
```

But the best and smartest way is the one that proposed Stefan and Lukasz Muzyka:

```
my_method(model_name, *["x", "y", "z"])
```

Comment: You could also use `id_var, attribute_1, attribute_2 = data` to assign the elements to variables.

Comment: you are right, but maybe this way is more readable or easy to understand